# using array elements for pattern matching in perl

Tags: regex, perl

A newbie to Perl and regexes without saying, I am trying to use elements in an array in a perl regex. Here is the snippet

```
my $temp  = $line =~ s/somestring[^\n]*$_// for @myarray;
```

If I hard code the string instead of $_ it works fine. Also $_ prints the string fine in isolation. So what am I doing wrong? Even the expanded version of using a for loop doesn't yield a match.

P.S Just to clarify the array has just one element and I know it matches the line.

Comment: I'm not a Perl dev, but in REGEX `$` has special meaning - it anchors to the end of the string, so it may need escaping.

Comment: @utkanos: Not necessary.  Scalar variable interpolation works just fine inside of Perl regular expressions.  perldoc perlop under the section "Quote and Quote Like Operators".

Comment: This is why I posted as a comment, not an answer. I was just saying that, in general REGEX grammar, the `$` has special meaning. I'm not a Perl dev, so I didn't commit - I was just floating the idea.

Comment: A little more code might help, like actual values that illustrate the problem.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish or how it is failing.

Comment: Thank you @RickF. It did turn out to be a rather trivial oversight/misconception on my part and my question was answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work adding parentheses, although I hope that the content of the array hasn't special characters, because you will need to use `quotemeta` function to escape them.

```
my $temp;
($temp  = $line) =~ s/somestring[^\n]*$_// for @myarray;
```

Comment: The "special characters" issue is a good point.  `s/somestring[^\n]*\Q$_\E//` is the more robust solution, unless the OP really wants the contents of `$_` to be treated as a pattern.

Comment: Thank you ! It helped. Robust solutions are always desirable. Helps me to start learning perl better.